# java ee maven project on intellij with tomcat cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

this is my first java ee project on IntelliJ and I want to use maven.

I create a java ee project on IntelliJ and add maven framework to it then move WEB-INF directory to src/main/resource and edit run configuration and set tomcat server local and fix it.
it's work and project run but if I add any  dependency to the pom file, for example, Jsoup or icu4j when run the project error 500 return whit this result:

```
An error occurred at line: [18] in the jsp file: [/index.jsp]
Jsoup cannot be resolved
15: 
16: <h1>Wellcome</h1>
17: <%
18:     Jsoup.connect("http://google.com");
19: %>
20: </body>
21: </html>
```

Comment: This sounds like a big mess.  Nothing you described doing sounds right for a Maven project.  [Check here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/) for some background on Maven projects.

Comment: Check that artifact you are deploying to Tomcat also includes the libraries you've added: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html.

Comment: After you changed pom.xml have you ran `mvn install` or enabled auto-import in IDEA? One of these steps is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tnx from @CrazyCoder my problem solve and I explain it here maybe help other. last setting I must do is going to `File->Project Strucher->Artifacts` then select the artifact and in the front of that in Output Layout tab in `Available Elements` section right click on libraries and select `Put into /WEB-INF/lib` or simply double-click on it.
with this setting, IntelliJ add library you add to pom in WEB-INF/lib then deploy it to server